# How to play ad at each array time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte

I am trying to play/show a video Advertisement(just a h1 tag) at each index value in the array. For example; the first item in the array is 5. **So **at 5 seconds, I want the video to pause and play an ad**. Then **again at 10 seconds**, then at 15.** Assume the currentTime variable increments from 0 seconds to the end of the video. How can I **trigger each ad to play when the currentTime value matches one of the adstream array index values**?

```
    let adStream: string;
    let currentTime = 0;
    let showAd: boolean = false;
    let adStartTimes: Array<number> = [5, 10, 15];  //How to trigger on each value in array???
    let storedStreamTime: number;
    let storedProgress: number;
    
    //Manually setting first index of array, but really want to check for matching index???
    $: if (Math.round(currentTime) === adStartTimes[0]) {
        //Pause the original video...
        videoElement && videoElement.pause();
        //Store the original progress and time...
        storedStreamTime = Math.round(currentTime);
        storedProgress = Math.round((currentTime / duration!) * 100);
        //Switch to the ad video, this should be the URI eventually, just a string for now...
        adStream = 'Ad Playing';
        //Show overlayed ad video...
        showAd = true;
    }

    //play the ad if showing...
    $: if (showAd) {
        playDummyAd();
    }

    const playDummyAd = () => {
        //after 5 second ad is done...
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('ad played');
            showAd = false;

            //return to current video time...
            currentTime = storedStreamTime + 1;
            progress = storedProgress + 1;

            //resume play of original video...
            videoElement.play();
        }, 5000);
    };
```

```
{#if showAd}
    <h1 class="p-4 text-white bg-red-500">{adStream}</h1>
{/if}
```

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for a repeating/recursive [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) or [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). In one of those, you could check what time the video is at to determine if it's time to play an ad. Other than that, your question is very vague and would benefit from breaking the problem down into more specific issues you're having and what you've tried to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the currentTime matches one of the `adStartTimes` values can be achieved with a reactive statement (since the user might seek, this should be independent of the index)

```js
$: isAdStartTime = adStartTimes.some(t => Math.floor(currentTime) === t)
$: if(isAdStartTime) handleAdPlayback()
```

When there's currently an ad played (probably unlikely, but still one of the `adStartTimes` might overlap with the length of an ad) or when the user is seeking over one of the start values, the playback should be prevented

```js
async function handleAdPlayback(){
        if(playAd || seeking) return
        playAd = true
        ...
    }
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fcc75e0adc714a86a026468b4c9da220?version=3.52.0)

```
<script>
    let video
    let currentTime
    let seeking

    let mainSrc = "https://sveltejs.github.io/assets/caminandes-llamigos.mp4"
    let adSrc = 'https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/021/520/113/mp4/abstract-falling-particle-animation-background-free-video.mp4'
    let src = mainSrc

    let adStartTimes = [5, 10, 15]

    let storedStreamTime
    let playAd = false
    let resumeMain = false

    $: isAdStartTime = adStartTimes.some(t => Math.floor(currentTime) === t)

    $: if(isAdStartTime) handleAdPlayback()

    async function handleAdPlayback(){
        if(playAd || seeking) return
        console.log('playAd - time', currentTime)
        playAd = true
        video.pause()
        storedStreamTime = currentTime
        src = adSrc //will trigger 'canplay'
    }

    function handleCanplay() {
        if(playAd) {
            console.log('canplay-playAd')           
            video.play()
        }
        if(resumeMain) {
            console.log('canplay-resumeMain')           
            video.play()
            resumeMain = false
        }
    }

    function handleEnded() {
        console.log('resume')
        if(!playAd) return
        playAd = false
        src = mainSrc //will trigger 'canplay'
        currentTime = storedStreamTime
        resumeMain = true
    }

</script>

<video controls
             bind:this={video}
             {src}
             bind:currentTime
             bind:seeking
             on:canplay={handleCanplay}
             on:ended={handleEnded}
             >
    <track kind="captions">
</video>

<style>
    video {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding I have modified some javascript code for check if currentTime match value inside the array of adStartTimes

Like this below code :-

```js
for (let i = 0; i < adStartTimes.length; i++) {
  if (Math.round(currentTime) === adStartTimes[i]) {
  
    videoElement && videoElement.pause();
    
    storedStreamTime = Math.round(currentTime);
    storedProgress = Math.round((currentTime / duration!) * 100);
    
    adStream = 'Ad Playing';    
    showAd = true;
  }
}
```

and **playDummyAd** function should accept the time

Like this below code :-

```js
const playDummyAd = (resumeTime: number) => {

  setTimeout(() => {

    showAd = false; 
    currentTime = resumeTime;

    progress = Math.round ( ( currentTime /duration!) * 100);    
    
    videoElement.play();

  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: okay so the only thing is when I call playDummyAd()  I need to pass in an argument, would this be the currenttime (the one that is incrementing)?